# A problem about limitation

Tags: calculus

I tried to use the Squeeze Theorem, but it failed, and I tried to deal with it using the definition of the definite integral, which also failed.
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{2k}{n^2+n+k} \right)^n = \frac{1}{e^{\frac{2}{3}}}$$